# Call an "initialize" function in an object when one of its member functions are called

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement lazy initializing in C++ and I am searching for a nice way to call the `Initialize()` member function when some other method like `object->GetName()` gets called.

Right now I have implemented it as follows:

```
class Person
{
protected:
    bool initialized = false;
    std::string name;

    void Initialize()
    {
        name = "My name!"; // do heavy reading from database
        initialized = true;
    }

public:
    std::string GetName()
    {
        if (!initialized) {
            Initialize();
        }

        return name;
    }
};
```

This does exactly what I need for the time being. But it is very tedious to setup the initialized check for every method, so I want to get rid of that. If someone knows a nice way in C++ to improve this above example, I would like to know!

Could maybe `operators` be used to achieve calling `Initialize()` when using `->` for example?

Thanks!

Comment: Initialise your object in the constructor.

Comment: @RichardCritten This defeats the purpose of lazy loading. Lazy loading is used so the objects data only get populated when actually trying to access the object. This is why you use the `initialized` mechanism.

Comment: How about having the `if (!initialized)` check in the `Initialize` function? Then all the `GetName` function have to do is call `Initialize()`.

Comment: You could use a lazy factory. Than the object will only be created, if it wasnt instanziated before with the given arguments.  Though it is not exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: If you access those objects via pointer, you could create your own smart pointer, that would call `Initialize()` in `operator->` and `get()` method. But this depends on how you actually want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for templates! Create a `lazily_initialized` wrapper that takes a type `T` and a *function object* `TInitializer` type:

```
template <typename T, typename TInitializer>
class lazily_initialized : TInitializer
{//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 // inheritance used for empty-base optimization

private:
    T _data;
    bool _initialized = false;

public:
    lazily_initialized(TInitializer init = {}) 
        : TInitializer(std::move(init))
    {
    }

    T& get()
    {
        if(!_initialized)
        {
            static_cast<TInitializer&>(*this)(_data);
            _initialized = true;
        }

        return _data;
    }
};
```

You can the use it as follows:

```
struct ReadFromDatabase
{
    void operator()(std::string& target) const
    {
        std::cout << "initializing...\n";
        target = "hello!";
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    lazily_initialized<std::string, ReadFromDatabase> _str;  
};
```

Example:

```
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo._str.get(); // prints "initializing...", returns "hello!"
    foo._str.get(); // returns "hello!"
}
```

[**example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Z2Akb6d4kULXUhKH)

---

As [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) mentioned in the comments, `std::optional<T>` or `boost::optional<T>` should be used instead of a separate `bool` field in order to represent the "uninitialized state". This allows *non default-constructible* types to be used with `lazily_initialized`, and also makes the code more elegant and safer.

As the former requires C++17 and the latter requires `boost`, I used a separate `bool` field to make my answer as simple as possible. A real implementation should consider using `optional`, using `noexcept` where appropriate, and also consider exposing a `const`-qualified `get()` that returns a `const T&`.

Comment: maybe `TInitializer::operator()` in place of `static_cast<TInitializer&>(*this)`

Comment: `optional<T>` might be better than `T` + `bool` for types without default constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42: I considered that but the question is marked as C++11.

Comment: I have not added namespace prefix to let `boost`/`std` usage depending of requirements ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe call it in the constructor?

Edit: Uh, i missed the point of your question sorry.
What about a lazy factory initialization?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization#C.2B.2B

Comment: @Aenons See my comment above. This defeats the whole purpose of lazy loading, so this is not the way to achieve it.